# How can I tell if Connection: keep-alive is working?

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient, fiddler

How can I tell if my HTTP connections are being reused when testing from a C# console application using HttpClient?

I'm sending the correct headers (according to Fiddler) but the timings are identical whether or not I send the Connection: keep-alive header.

I'm curious to know if it's always working (even without the header) or always *not* working.

My code to set it up is as follows (and I'm reusing the same instance each time):

```
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Connection.ToString()))
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
    }
```

As an aside: I can't see an easier way to set this header directly - you can only Add() to it. That means if you call the method twice, you end up with "keep-alive, keep-alive" as the value!

Comment: The oldschool way would be to fire up *Wireshark* and look at the network connection. If everything transmitted is in the same TCP stream, everything's fine. If multiple connections to the target server are opened, they're not respecting `Connection: keep-alive`, but that's very unlikely anyways if you'r querying a standard webserver like Apache, nginx, IIS etc. You may only see a performance benefit for this for really many files.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the easiest way is to use timings and explicitly disable it to get a reference.  The .net version HttpClient appears to reuse the connection automatically *by default* as long as the remote server sends the correct header in it's response.

However, if you explicitly set the Connection header to "close" then the remote server will close the connection.  After doing this, all the timings were 200ms slower for each request, proving that keep-alive was working OK all along.